# Getting Azure Blob Storage AccessToken with AzureAD account

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service, azure-blob-storage

I have seen many examples of how to use RBAC and request a bearer token using a registered app for which you give access to your blob storage account or container.

What I need instead is to give access to a specific group of users in an AzureAD group and now request an access token as an individual user, without any application (clietn_id) in between.

Would someone help/guide me to achieving that with a tool like postman for example.
Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: You can just use direct AAD access if interactive login is acceptable. No requesting bearer tokens or any of that

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid need to get it silently.
I do that currently for Graph using the GetTokenSilentlyWithWebAccountAsync.
I need to do that programmatically eventually with no interaction. Suppose all the required authorization is done on the Azure portal side.
This is why I asked how I would do it with postman. A sample code would be as useful.

Answer (score 0):

Azure AD tokens are requested trough registered or enterprise apps. You will need a client id in between.

If you want to authenticate a user programmatically you will need to implement the [ROPC flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc). [Click here for the Postman request](https://www.postman.com/lmedenred/workspace/lm-s-public-workspace/example/11230239-ffc07892-0147-4cd9-ba16-9d6b7c5e6dfb). Keep in mind ROPC is not recommended, do not support personal accounts or passwordless logins, MFA and others.

Remember to [Grant your registered app permissions to Azure Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-auth-aad-app?toc=%2Fazure%2Fstorage%2Fblobs%2Ftoc.json&tabs=dotnet#grant-your-registered-app-permissions-to-azure-storage) and set the scope parameter to `https://storage.azure.com/user_impersonation` in Postman.